# Mouse out and change backGround tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

In master page

Script:

```
         $(".RightMenu").click(function(){ 

                $(".FlashMenu").css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/blueFlash30.png)');   
                $('.RightMenu').css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/Menu.png)');                

                $(this).css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/MenuActive.png)');
                $(this).css('background-repeat','repeat-x');

                $(this).find(">:first-child").css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/greenflash30.png)');
                $(this).find(">:first-child").css('background-repeat','no-repeat');  



         });
         $(".RightMenu").mouseover(function(){ 

                $('.RightMenu').css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/Menu.png)');                

                $(this).css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/MenuOver.png)');
                $(this).css('width','150px');
                $(this).css('height','20px');
                $(this).css('background-repeat','repeat-x');                        

         });
```

Style:

```
    div.RightMenu
    {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        text-align: right;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 20px;
        float: right;
        width: 150px;
        background-image: url(icon/PersonalPage/Menu.png);
        border: 1px solid #ede7da;
    }
    div.FlashMenu
    {
        background-image: url(icon/PersonalPage/blueFlash30.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        width: 30px;
        height: 20px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td  valign="top" colspan="1" width="185px">
                <div id="ContentRightMenu" >
                    <div class="RightMenu">
                        Home
                        <div class="FlashMenu">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="RightMenu">
                        About
                        <div class="FlashMenu">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="RightMenu">
                        Product
                        <div class="FlashMenu">
                        </div>
                    </div>

         </tr>
 </table>
```

======================================================
1.

When the mouse moves over `Div.RightMenu` change its image (Menu.png==>MenuOver.png).

But when the mouse out from `div.ContentRightMenu`.one of the `Div.RightMenu`colors of the same color as the mouse over(MenuOver.png) stays in and not to be the first case(Menu.png)

2.

When me click on a `Div.RightMenu` gets its color from the default(Menu.png) will change with the new state(MenuActive.png) But when the mouse move is doing the color returns to its initial state(MenuActive.png==>Menu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to make use of the bind/unbind jQuery functions. Additionally you will have to make use of the mouseout event that developerdoug mentioned.

```
function rightMenuClick()
{
    $(".FlashMenu").css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/blueFlash30.png)');   
    $(".RightMenu").css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/Menu.png)');   
    $(".RightMenu").bind('mouseover', rightMenuMouseOver);
    $(".RightMenu").bind('mouseout', rightMenuMouseOut);                
    $(this).css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/MenuActive.png)');
    $(this).css('background-repeat','repeat-x');
    $(this).find(">:first-child").css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/greenflash30.png)');
    $(this).find(">:first-child").css('background-repeat','no-repeat');     
    $(this).unbind('mouseout');
    $(this).unbind('mouseover');
}           
function rightMenuMouseOut()
{               
    $(this).css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/Menu.png)');                              
}           
function rightMenuMouseOver()
{           
    $(this).css('background-image','url(icon/PersonalPage/MenuOver.png)');              
}                   
$(".RightMenu").bind('click', rightMenuClick);       
$(".RightMenu").bind('mouseover', rightMenuMouseOver);
$(".RightMenu").bind('mouseout', rightMenuMouseOut);
```

Comment: tank you very very very very very much.

Answer (score 1):

try using mouseout instead of mouseover